# z-index with submit button not playing nice

Tags: css, input, z-index, layer

I'm wracking my brain over this and can't figure it out. I have overlapping DIVs but I cannot get the submit button (login) to be on top.

http://swaptoria.com/

You'll see on the right there is the login button and a DIV from the main area thats preventing the button from being clickable.

Any advice would be most appreciated!

Comment: Your HTML is a mess. Don't expect anyone to reverse-engineer your page to figure this out.

Comment: we aint reading the entire code??? Post the part that is relevant.

Comment: 1) You should only use ids for UNIQUE items. There should never be a duplicate id on the page. 2) You are setting the width's of your `#ImgRB` divs to `381px`. (line 240 on the page), so they are expanding out of their containers and overlaying your form on the right. Setting the width to a smaller value solves this problem.

Comment: @Diodeus Reverse engineering is not necessary.  Suggestion: checkout the chrome (or IE) developer tools.  Pretty rockin!

Comment: That's exactly what reverse engineering is, Jememy. A soon as I see someone using TABLES for layouts, I usually run in the other direction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your login button's position is static so its z-index wont be considered, change it to `position: relative;` z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).

Comment: +1 Tested and this works using `position:relative`.  Good work!

Comment: Thank you so much Musa! That did it! I know the HTML is a mess - I guess thats what I get for outsourcing my coding overseas!!!